# Since neutrinos have mass, is there a neutrino aether that could be detected by a Michelson-Morley experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, interference, neutrinos, aether

If there are trillions of neutrinos per second passing through my body each second, would this density of particles qualify as a neutrino aether?  If so, it seems in principle that an interference-type experiment might detect it. The claim that most of the neutrinos come from the Sun indicates that the flux of neutrinos might have a detectable favored direction.  There seems no current evidence, however, of what might be termed "neutrino drag" for planetary bodies.

Comment: Why are you calling it a neutrino aether? The aether was the hypothetical medium for EM waves, but neutrinos aren't acting as a medium for any kind of wave.

Comment: We get more energetic neutrinos from the Sun than from other stars for basically the same reason that we get more light from the Sun than from other stars. OTOH, there are a *lot* of low energy neutrinos which are remnants from the Big Bang, but their energy is way below the threshold of our detectors.

Answer (score 1):

Aether in the sense originally thought-of in the late 1800s was to provide a medium in which electromagnetic waves can propagate. This turned out to be unnecessary and wrong. I take your question to be independent of that nomenclature though.

Aether to me implies a wave-like substance. The deBroglie wavelength of particles is $\hbar/p$ and for the wave picture to be appropriate, your phase space density should be larger than that wavelength, such that the individual waves overlap. This might be the case only for super-slow neutrinos, but certainly not for those coming from the Sun, which have nuclear energies of $\sim 1\mathrm{MeV}$ and are thus relativistic.

There is the Cosmic Neutrino Background of very cold (slow) neutrinos, relics from the Big Bang. This can in principle be detected using extremely sensitive torsion balances, but current technology is still a few orders of magnitude away in sensitivity.

Unlike the hypothetical (and wrong) concept of Aether, these neutrinos are particles and need to interact with something, so a Michelson–Morley type interferometer is not sensitive to the Cosmic Neutrino Background.

In any case the momentum and cross section of neutrinos is so tiny that even given their huge number density, macroscopic effects such as drag on planets is utterly negligible, by orders of magnitude of orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. My thinking was that these particles have a wavelength and that directional interferometry might provide some insight. I think your answer, while not specifying numerical wavelengths, suggests that such measurements may be possible in principle but not in practice. The concept of measurement by torsion balance is interesting to me, partly because it may suggest discovery of weakly interacting entities. I wonder if deep space is an appropriate location for such measurements.

Comment: I think aether (not "luminiferous aether") is a popular and more general term for something that permeates all of space.  Spirituals use the term.  Perhaps the Cosmic Neutrino Background might qualify. Also the quantum structure of space.

Comment: Yes, a measurement of the Cosmic Neutrino Background is possible in principle but with given technology not in the decade to come. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1529 for some quantitative considerations.